# Android - Best way to store a list of objects (Storing Chat History)

Tags: android, android-room

So I'm writing a chat application and I need to store each users chat log locally. I'm using Room to do this.

User class:

```
@PrimaryKey
@NonNull
private String userid;
private String name;;

@TypeConverters(Object_Converter.class)
private ArrayList<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
```

The issue I'm having is updating the List of messages.

I'm currently using the default @Update method:

```
@Update
void updateUser(User user);
```

So basically every time a message is received by my listener, it will request the user by Id, then get the list of messages and then add to it, and finally call updateUser.

My question is how detrimental to performance is this method since I assume updateUser just overwrites the entire list of messages with a new one? Messages can be recieved every few moments so is their a better way to store and update a user chat history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. All messages will be overwritten by update. It would be best to store messages in its own table with a foreign key to sending and receiving user. Basically your message would look like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "message", foreignKeys = {
    @ForeignKey(
            entity = User.class,
            parentColumns = "userid",
            childColumns = "senderId",
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    ),
    @ForeignKey(
            entity = User.class,
            parentColumns = "userid",
            childColumns = "receiverId",
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
    )
}, indices = {
        @Index("senderId"),
        @Index("receiverId")
})
public class Message {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long id;
    public String senderId;
    public String receiverId;
    public String content;
    // ... other stuff
}
```

And then you would just insert and delete messages when needed. When you want to retrieve messages you could just retrieve it with `userid` or you could join tables and create another model class which would contain user and list of sent and receieved messages.

It's never a good idea to store a list as a column because it indicated that a new table is needed. For more information read about [database normal form](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is more about the design of the database, rather than the implementation.
I'd go about this issue like this: 
You can create a new database entity for the Messages and use a foreign key to connect the two entities. That would be one-to-many relationship where each user can have more messages. Then, you would simply insert each new message in the second table and get the list of messages with a query, i.e:

```
"SELECT message FROM messages WHERE userid = :id"
```

or something similar. The main point is, you need to change your database structure.